# AWS API Gateway, default base mappings with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm setting up an environment with AWS CDK but I'm having trouble with API Gateway and base mappings for custom domains.

I got an API that should have two stages: "internal" and "external".
Whenever I create a new RestApi and either specify domainName as a prop to the construcor, or use the addDomainName method afterwards. This will always create a default Base Mapping, which I do not want. I want to add my own mappings like this:

```
apiGateway.domainName.addBasePathMapping(apiGateway, { basePath: 'internal', stage: internalStage });
apiGateway.domainName.addBasePathMapping(apiGateway, { basePath: 'external', stage: externalStage });
```

The problem if I do the above is that the default mapping have already been created and since it will be created with an empty basePath, I can't add any other mappings to the same API.

I've checked the source code and there does not seem to be a way to pass mappings when you add a domain, they are always created automatically.

Is there a way to change the default mappings, or to get pass this problem in another way?
Example that would be nice:
`apiGateway.domainName.basePathMappings[0] = { ... }`

My code right now:

```
const apiGateway = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'RestApi', {
  deploy: false,
  domainName: {
    domainName: 'sub.example.com',
    certificate,
    endpointType: apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
    securityPolicy: apigw.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
  },
});
const deployment = new apigw.Deployment(this, 'Deployment', { api: apiGateway });

const internalStage = new apigw.Stage(this, 'InternalStage', {
  stageName: 'internal',
  deployment,
});
apiGateway.domainName.addBasePathMapping(apiGateway, { basePath: 'internal', stage: internalStage });

const externalStage = new apigw.Stage(this, 'ExternalStage', {
  stageName: 'external',
  deployment,
});
apiGateway.domainName.addBasePathMapping(apiGateway, { basePath: 'external', stage: externalStage });
```

The generated syntax when i run Synth, will show 3 different AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping.
One for internal, one for external (with basePath set correctly) and one is the default created one with no basePath (which I want gone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment we add a domainName either by passing to RestApi or by calling `.addDomainName` , cdk is adding a base path mapping `/`.

I was able to work around by using cfn resources for DomainName and Base path mapping.

```
const cfnInternalDomain = new apigw.CfnDomainName(this, "internal-domain", {
  domainName: internalDomainName,      
  regionalCertificateArn: myCert.certificateArn,
  endpointConfiguration: { types: [apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL] },
});
const intBasePath = new apigw.CfnBasePathMapping(
  this,
  "internal-base-path",
  {
    basePath: "intPath",
    domainName: cfnInternalDomain.ref,
    restApiId: myRestApi.restApiId,
    stage: internalStage.stageName,
  }
);
```

This is full code.

```
const myRestApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, "rest-api", {
  deploy: false,
});
myRestApi.root.addMethod("ANY", new apigw.MockIntegration());
const deployment = new apigw.Deployment(this, "api-deployment", {
  api: myRestApi,
  retainDeployments: false,
});
const internalStage = new apigw.Stage(this, "internal-stage", {
  stageName: "internal",
  deployment,
});
const internalDomainName = "internal.mytest.domain.com";
const cfnInternalDomain = new apigw.CfnDomainName(this, "internal-domain", {
  domainName: internalDomainName,      
  regionalCertificateArn: myCert.certificateArn,
  endpointConfiguration: { types: [apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL] },
});
const intBasePath = new apigw.CfnBasePathMapping(
  this,
  "internal-base-path",
  {
    basePath: "intPath",
    domainName: cfnInternalDomain.ref,
    restApiId: myRestApi.restApiId,
    stage: internalStage.stageName,
  }
);
```

Comment: Excellent! It worked perfectly and as a bonus I've now learned about CFN constructs. Thank you very much

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Comment: I attempted to use this same method, which works great until you attempt to create an route53.ARecord.  At which point you get an error:  "API does not define a default domain name"

You can recreate this by following up your code with:

      const aRecord = new route53.ARecord(this, 'theARecord', {
        recordName: 'sub.example.com',
        zone: route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'theZone', {
              domainName: 'example.com'}),
        target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.ApiGateway(myRestApi))
      });

Now try synth'ing.  This is where it errors